# only pulling one link out using regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

Hi I have the following code and I only want to pull out links that have www. in them

```
<p> Text < href="http://url.com/link/">link text</a> more text < href="http://www.anotehrurl.com/">more link text</a> and < href="http://www.anotherurl.com/sub/sub/link.html">link text</a>. more text < href="http://keepurl.co.uk/link/">link text</a> more text < href="http://www.anotherurl.com/sub/sub/link.html">link text</a>. < href="http://www.anotherurl.com/sub/sub/link.html">link text</a>.  < href="http://www.anotehrurl.com/">more link text</a></p>
```

im using the reg expression:

```
(<a href="http:\/\/www.[\d\D]*?\/">([\d\D]*?)<\/a>)
```

basically I want to match any link that starts with www and not match any link that is keepurl.co.uk/.......

I have put this through rubular and come out with following:

{
Result 1

1.< href="http://www.anotehrurl.com/">more link text
2.more link text
Result 2

1.< href="http://www.anotherurl.com/sub/sub/link.html">link text. more text 
< href="http://keepurl.co.uk/link/">link text
2.link text
Result 3

1.< href="http://www.anotherurl.com/sub/sub/link.html">link text. < href="http://www.anotherurl.com/sub/sub/link.html">link text. < href="http://www.anotehrurl.com/">more link text
2.more link text
}

as u can see its pulling out more than i want.

cheers

Comment: how do i get all the code to show up propperly

Comment: on my previouse questions someone must have done something as all the html and php is visible

Comment: Indent your code by 4 spaces, or select it and press the `{}` button in the toolbar!

Comment: Do you parse whole html page, or just some snippets? Maybe you should consider using DOMDocument or any other html parser for php?

Comment: just snippits I know there is prob better ways of doing it but at mo my code is close to finished and i dont have the life will power to rewrite just yet!

Comment: Why don't you apply **any** of the advises from you last two questions?

Comment: Hi mario, not quite sure what you mean why dont I apply any of the advises from my last two questions?  All the questions are separate entities and are all to do something specific.  Its not possible to use one answer for the other problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
       <?php
        $html = <<<END
   <p> Text < href="http://url.com/link/">link text</a> more text
       < href="http://www.anotehrurl.com/">more link text</a>
       and < href="http://www.anotherurl.com/sub/sub/link.html">link text</a>.
       more text < href="http://keepurl.co.uk/link/">link text</a> more text
       < href="http://www.anotherurl.com/sub/sub/link.html">link text</a>.
       < href="http://www.anotherurl.com/sub/sub/link.html">link text</a>.
       < href="http://www.anotehrurl.com/">more link text</a></p>
END;


        $r = '#href=\"http://(www\.[^\"]*)\">(.+)</#iU';

        preg_match_all($r, $html, $m);

        var_dump($m[1]);
        var_dump($m[2]);
        ?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
array
  0 => string 'www.anotehrurl.com/' (length=19)
  1 => string 'www.anotherurl.com/sub/sub/link.html' (length=36)
  2 => string 'www.anotherurl.com/sub/sub/link.html' (length=36)
  3 => string 'www.anotherurl.com/sub/sub/link.html' (length=36)
  4 => string 'www.anotehrurl.com/' (length=19)
array
  0 => string 'more link text' (length=14)
  1 => string 'link text' (length=9)
  2 => string 'link text' (length=9)
  3 => string 'link text' (length=9)
  4 => string 'more link text' (length=14)
```

Comment: Not quite sure why when I tried your exact version I couldnt get it to work but I used part of your answer and my existing code and now it works thanks marcin :)

Comment: heres what I used in the end /(<a href="http:\/\/www\.[^\"]*">([\d\D]*?)<\/a>)/

Answer (score 0):

```
/<a.+?href="([http:\/\/]?www\..+?)".+?>/i
```

something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have got the text saved in the `$string` variable, this should work out for you.

```
preg_match('@href="(http://www\.(?!keepurl.co.uk).*?)"@i', $string, $m);
```

Where `($!regex)` does a:

> Zero-width negative lookahead. Identical to positive lookahead, except that the overall match will only succeed if the regex inside the lookahead fails to match.

A good [regular expression reference page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html).